# Getting list of user authorities returns empty list on root/index request mapping after logging in

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-security, spring-boot

I have the following request mapping that is used for the index page of my app upon logging in.  I have an argument resolver for my `Person` type which gives me me the currently logged in user.  While running in debug, I can inspect `currentUser` and see the user's authorities, but the resulting `authorities` collection is always empty when it's added to the model.  So I'm kind of scratching my head as to why.  I'm using JPA to get the user's information from the database.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Model model, Person currentUser) {
    Collection<String> authorities = currentUser.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedApplication::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList());
    model.addAttribute("authorities", authorities);
    return "index";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out on my `Person` type, I just needed to set fetching to eager on authorities and it works...

Before

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "UACODE", referencedColumnName = "USRCODE")
private Collection<GrantedApplication> authorities;
```

After

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "UACODE", referencedColumnName = "USRCODE")
private Collection<GrantedApplication> authorities;
```